# mdframed package

Tags: mdframed

Good day. Any idea how to recreate this using mdframed package?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? (And just to be sure: you are not interested in a `tcolorbox` solution, are you?)

Comment: As an alternative to mdframed one could also try recreating it as a tikz-flowchart. I don‘t know whether it is possible to create such a box with mdframed.

Comment: This is possible by using `tcolorbox` without much strain, do you expect this with `mdframed` only else to switch over to `tcolorbox`, confirm...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508287/134144 might be helpful. In this answer to a previous question, I have included a version using `mdframed` as well as a `tcolorbox` alternative. The colors and the exact position of the title can of course be adjusted to suit your needs.

Comment: There is something of similar to the Example 5 – complex example with TikZ of the manual `mdframed` pag. 27.